# Is that true that a sharepoint 2010 Full Crawl cannot start while an incremental crawl is running?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, crawling, fast-search, incremental-crawl

I am using SharePoint 2010 with Fast Search. A full crawl is set up to running `weekly at 12:00 am every Saturday`. and the Incremental Crawl is set up `every 15 minutes for 24 hours every day`.

And I found out a incremental crawl took more than 2 hours which cross the window that full crawl was supposed to run.As result of it, the Full Crawl wasn't trigger at all because I didn't see any log history record regarding to it.

My understanding is the full crawl should be triggered after the incremental crawl finished, but it seems not true.

Are there anybody who can share the expertise about this and how to solve this issue? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is not correct. So rule, if a crawl is running and schedule for another crawl schedule (Lets say full) on the same content source is approached then running crawl always took the priority & continue. Now Full crawl will be skipped and wait for the next schedule which is next week in your case.

If you don't want to overlap them then i think, run the incremental crawl for 6 days and Run full crawl on Sunday. As your incremental took 2 hours then full need more time.

Another approach will be manually run the full crawl.

Comment: And I usually ask..why the full crawl?

Comment: Once a week full crawl is not a good practice? any particular reason we shouldn't ? thanks